# Create maven repository in web hosting

Tags: maven, repository, maven-3

I need to host several jar files in maven repository. There are may free web hosting companies which provide free web space. Do I need some special configuration to create a simple maven repository and upload maven jars?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, a Maven repository is simply a place to store and retrieve files from. Nowadays, this is mainly done via the HTTP protocol. In an over-simplified example (as it was in the early days of Maven), things were simply hosted in a web server - you would deploy them via an `HTTP PUT` and retrieve them over `HTTP GET`. As things evolved, Maven artifact repository managers evolved and they started keeping record of various kinds of metadata.

As an over-simplified answer: if you have a proper `<distributionManagement/>` and `<repositories/>` section in your `pom.xml` and you can issue `HTTP PUT` and `HTTP GET` operations against a web server, then you can store these artifacts in a web server, if you really don't want to use an artifact repository manager (which is not really advisable, but hey, who am I to stop you?!). Clearly, this example doesn't cover adding credentials (which is handled by the Maven `settings.xml`'s `<servers/>` id mappings to `<repository/>` id-s.

If your free hosting service allows you to install an artifact repository manager, you should consider picking one and installing it.